# How to upsert an existing spark dataframe with a new Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which includes all the existing records.I have received a new Dataframe from which I have to update the existing Dataframe and as well as  insert the new record present in the new Dataframe.  The schema is same in both df. Primary key is identity number.

Comment: If the schema and keys match, have you tried to `join` them?

Comment: To update and insert into  the existing df with the new df records which join should I use? Inner join following by a Anti left ?

Comment: Can you try it and tell us if that doesn't work?

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically left-anti join to get the old records not in the new and then union to the df with the new records